# How to show the slideshow of embedded videos?

Tags: asp.net

[image]

Can anybody give me the Javascript to integrate the YouTube video thumbnails, in order to create slideshow just like in the image above? (And these videos should be able to uploaded from FTP if possible)

Comment: Post what you have tried so far?

Comment: These are the things so far I found. But I dont think these are helpful.http://demo.awkward.se/showcase/                                     http://jquery-slideshow.com/jquery-slideshow-slideshow-thumbnails.html